# Integrating JavaScript and QML in the same file

Tags: javascript, qml

can we integrate QML and JavaScript code in the same .qml file as we do it in HTML JS
For example:

```
//test.qml
import QtQuick 1.0
Item 
{
    function pollLoginStatus()
    {
        var receiveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    ....
QML Code
```

I know that we have to use JavaScript using.

```
    import "jsCode.js" as jsCode

    Item
    {
         jsCode.jsfunction();
```

Is there anyother way of doing it, I want to integrate QML and JavaScript in the same file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have JS in QMl files.

See:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativejavascript.html

First example:

```
 Item {
     function factorial(a) {
         a = parseInt(a);
         if (a <= 0)
             return 1;
         else
             return a * factorial(a - 1);
     }

     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: console.log(factorial(10))
     }
 }
```

Keep the restrictions in mind:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativejavascript.html#qml-javascript-restrictions

Comment: when i write `Item { var oneVar =10; .... rest of code}` then it gives me Syntax error on deceleration var. where can i define global variables for java script? and is it possible to load an QML page from the JavaScript.

Comment: You don't use "var", instead you should use "property". "var" is can be used only inside of function or in separate JS file.